# 8002f310 error does not go to safe mode

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

PS3 gives error 8002f310 and no matter what you do does not go to safe mode. Was doing a system update, gave me this error. Running to 99%,says previous install was canceled. The system is attempting to install again. Do not turn off system. After install operation has completed the system will automatically restart.
Then gives error code 8002f310,occurred during update. Press power button on the front until system beeps. Next unplug AC from outlet. After a few minutes restart the system. Update will resume automatically when system is restarted.
If it fails again contact Technical support for assistance withe error code 8002f310

Is there a way to solve this problem?